# Kohana 3 ORM query using NOTIN()

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

Is there a way to use a http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in with Kohana's ORM? Something like:

```
$products = ORM::factory('products')->notin('contry_id', $csl)->find_all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use where statement:

```
$products = ORM::factory('products')->where('contry_id', 'NOT IN', $csl)->find_all();
```

$csl must be array

Comment: thanks, I just tried that but forgot to change the $csl param to an array, so your answer was in good time!